# Can't find Python's 2to3 utility on Fedora 20

Tags: python

I can't seem to find Python's 2to3 conversion tool anywhere on Fedora 20. I can't find an RPM (except an old OpenSUSE one) either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binary is included within the `python-tools` package. You can find these packages using yum's `whatprovides` functionality:

```
yum whatprovides /usr/bin/2to3
```

You can then install it using:

```
yum install python-tools
```

Comment: For Fedora30, the equivalent would be `dnf whatprovides /usr/bin/2to3` and `dnf install python3-devel`.